# Reference a solution item in VB project

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio

I'm trying to do something quite simple. I've added an item to the 'Solution Items' folder of my Visual Studio VB .net project. The item is called 'ValidationQuery.sql' and I need to reference it in my code. However, I can't seem to figure out how to actually reference it.

Comment: What do you mean "Reference" it? Read its contents?

Answer (score 0):

Sql scripts are not for reference purpose. The sql scripts are executed in sql server and they create object in sql server.

You can reference only dll's in the project.

Now use ado.net to access those object i.e. tables, views, sp's from database from .net code.